# Converting string to double exception

Tags: c#, exception

I am beginner in C#. I'm trying to convert a `string` to `double`. Here is the code with the method `double.Parse()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s="0.5";
    double b = double.Parse(s);
    Console.WriteLine("double.Parse() - {0}",b);
}
```

I tried with `System.Convert.ToDouble()` too:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s="0.5";
    double b = System.Convert.ToDouble(s);
    Console.WriteLine("Convert.ToDouble() - {0}",b);
}
```

In both ways the Program throws Exception:

> "Input string was not in a correct format".

Please help!!!. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have comma `,` as decimal digits separator in your current culture

Comment: Both examples should just run fine from .net 2.0 - 4.5.1. Could you just paste the complete source including using statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your current culture has ',' as the decimal separator, if that is the case, either use "0,5" instead of "0.5" or change the separator:

```
var s="0.5";
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
var b = double.Parse(s, culture);

Console.WriteLine("double.Parse() - {0}",b);
```

Try that, and see if it fixes it.

Comment: when i copy the text, there was error in CustureInfo, but when i edit the text, it work.Really thank you!

Comment: ah okay just updated now with something that work on my pc. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

As Sergey Berezovskiy commented, this is probably because your machine's culture uses , instead of . as the decimal separator. If you want to force it to use . (consider the implications) you must use parse using an [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). At the bottom of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there are a lot of examples on how to achieve this.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the Invariant Culture.

Answer (score 2):

Sergey is [completely right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651108/converting-string-to-double-exception#comment32722489_21651108).

Both [`Convert.ToDouble` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Double.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) use [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a default.

And looks like your current culture's [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `.` and that's why your code throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As a solution, you can set your `NumberDecimalSeparator` to `.` in your code before you parsing it.

```
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
c.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
double b = Double.Parse(s, c); // Or Convert.ToDouble(s, c)
```

And by the way, using the `Convert.ToDouble(String)` method is equivalent to `Double.Parse(String)` method.